# Using maya python api - how do I change selected object name into upper case?

Tags: python, maya-api

I have the following code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

list = cmds.ls(sl=True)

my_list = [object.upper() for object in list]

print(my_list)
```

However, it doesn't change the name of the objects even though it prints out upper case names in the print statement at the end.

Comment: can't anyway. strings are immutables

Comment: What kind of objects are these `object`s?

Comment: [The objects are strings](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/ls.html)

Comment: Thanks. Okay. Because I have objects name pCube1... and i want to change to upperCase.

Comment: I'm highly appreciated with the answer. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

list = cmds.ls(sl=True)
for n in list:
    cmds.rename(n, n.upper())

new_list = cmds.ls(sl=True)
print(new_list)
```

This is [documented here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/) with an example.

This code will rename all objects in `list` you can also work with whichever you have selected with `cmds.select()` if you want to.

Comment: @epadilla great - please don't forget to hit the tick mark :)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to “mutate” a string is to use slicing and concatenation
to build a new string by copying from parts of the old string.

Comment: Thanks. For Example i have different objects selected and i want to change the name of the objects to upperCase.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hackish, and I honestly wouldn't recommend it, but if you REALLY want to do that, you could do:

```
def global_var_to_upper(var):
    for _ in globals():
        if var is globals()[_]:
            globals()[str(_).upper()] = globals()[_]
            del globals()[_]
            break

abc = 123
global_var_to_upper(abc)
print(ABC) # prints 123
```

Comment: Whilst I appreciate the ingenuity - I don't think that's what the OP is after (changing the actual variable name).  I think they're talking about object names within `maya`.  Could be wrong, of course.

Comment: I was basing this off of the "It doesn't change the name of the objects only the results" which, I assume (albeit certainly don't know), is referring to the NAME of the object. Of course, you could very well be right. OP is fairly vague.

Comment: Yeah - based on OP comment on my answer, I've edited the Q to be more specific.  TBH - I'm impressed with your trick to rename the actual object name!

Comment: Great. I'll try this. Many Thanks!

Comment: @JRichardSnape I hope this isn't condescending, but it just creates a new reference to the original object and deletes that original one. It is a neat trick though.